# send email birthdate to all contact in CRM 365 with workflow C#?

Tags: c#, linq

How can I send email birthday to all contact in CRM 365 with workflow [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) ?

The code I wrote:

```
var today = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-90);
var contacts = from c in orgContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
    where (c.BirthDate != null && c.BirthDate.Value.Month == today.Month)
    where (c.BirthDate != null && c.BirthDate.Value.Day == today.Day)
    select new { c.Id, c.LogicalName, c.BirthDate, c.FullName };
```

I get an error in the [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) where condition:

> Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Comment: which error your are getting ?

Comment: Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method

Answer (score 0):

Try following with removing `Value` property from dates and convert result set to list using `ToList()`

```
  var contacts = (from c in orgContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
                   where (c.BirthDate != null && c.BirthDate.Month == today.Month
                                              && c.BirthDate.Day == today.Day)                      
                   select new { c.Id, c.LogicalName, c.BirthDate, c.FullName}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need 'Value'.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace Oppgave3Lesson1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context orgContext = new Context();
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

            var contacts = from c in orgContext.CreateQuery<Contact>()
                           //remoived value
                           where (c.BirthDate != null && c.BirthDate.Month == today.Month)
                           where (c.BirthDate != null && c.BirthDate.Day == today.Day)
                           select new { c.Id, c.LogicalName, c.BirthDate, c.FullName };
        }
    }
    public class Context
    {
        public List<Contact> CreateQuery<Contact>()
        {
            return new List<Contact>
        }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LogicalName { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help but I can not remoived value .I have this error:'DateTime?' does not contain a definition for 'Month' and no extension method 'Month' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)